# How to display small images within the diagram in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, image, uiview

I have created myView which is subclass of `UIView` and drawn a circle on the myView. Now i want to display small images within the circle , not outside of the circle. But i got inside circle and outside circle that means the images are displayed on whole myVIew.

I got like as following picture as

[image]

But i would like to get as following as

[image]

Is it possible or not? Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the ellipse is an `UIBezierPath`, you can use:

```
UIImage *patternImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"thePattern.png"];
UIColor *fillPattern = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:patternImage];
[fillPattern setFill]; 
[thePath fill];
```

**EDIT**

Fill ellipse created by `CGContextAddEllipseInRect` using pattern image:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {

    CGImageRef patternImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"file"].CGImage;
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextAddEllipseInRect(context, CGRectMake(100, 100, 200, 200));
    CGContextClip(context);
    CGContextDrawTiledImage(context, CGRectMake(20, 20, 48, 36),patternImage);

}
```

Comment: Thanks for replay. I didn't use UIBezierPath. I used CGContextAddEllipseInRect method. Please suggest me.

Comment: Thank you very much. I've almost tried today as you have written but didn't use CGContextClip. That's why i didn't get it. Finally i got it  because of your help.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

`#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>`

and in your code , after making the circle , add the image and set these:
`myImageView.layer.cornerRadius = x;`

`myImageView.layer.masksToBounds = TRUE;`

This allows you to have rounded corners on your image. And if you calculate the radius to match your circle , you should get the desired look.

Hope this helps.

Cheers,

George

Comment: Thanks George. I got it. But it is work for circle, not for triangle,pentagon.